# Jquery passing value to controller (codeigniter)

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter-3

I have a problem that I can´t solve. My goal is to show all members from
the group that is selected in the list. I have come so far that I can see
the selected group in the console but I can´t figure it out how to pass it to the controller. Hopefully someone understands my problem. My code is below.

Members_view.php

```
<select id="group_id">

<?php foreach($groups->result() as $row){?>

<option value="<?php echo $row->group; ?>" ><?php echo $row->group; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>

 <ul>
 <?php foreach($members->result() as $row){?>
 <li><?php echo $row->firstname." ".$row->lastname; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
 </ul>
```

Jquery.js

```
$('#group_id').change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var base = '<?=base_url()?>';
    var grp = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base + "members/members",
        data: { "group_id": grp },
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
            console.log(grp);
        }
    });
});
```

Members.php

```
 function members(){
    $group_id = $this->input->post('group_id',true);

    $data['groups'] = $this->mdl_members->_all_groups();
    $data['members'] = $this->mdl_members->_members($group_id);
    $this->load->view('members_view',$data);
}
```

Mdl_members.php

```
function _all_groups(){
  $sql = $this->db->query("select * from groups");
  return $sql;
}

function _members($id){
$sql = $this->db->query("select * from members WHERE group_id = '$id'");
return $sql;
}
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

*Mdl_members.php*: The model returns data, I do prefer `arrays`.

```
function _all_groups(){
  $sql = $this->db->query("select * from groups");
  return $sql->result_array();
}

function _members($id){
$sql = $this->db->query("select * from members WHERE group_id = '$id'");
return $sql->result_array();
}
```

*Members.php*: take a look at the new `members_view()` method. He's calling the `view` with `_all_groups()` data to the `select`.

```
function members_view(){
        $data['groups'] = $this->_all_groups();
        $this->load->view('members_view',$data);
    }

function members(){
    $group_id = $this->input->post('group_id',true);
    $members = $this->_members($group_id);
    echo json_encode($members);
}
```

*Jquery.js*: just some lines in the `success: function(resp)` to get `json` response from `members()` and put it in `<ul id="resp">`.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#group_id').change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var base = '<?=base_url()?>';
        var grp = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: base+"members/members",
            data: {"group_id": grp},
            dataType: "JSON",
            cache: false,
            success: function(resp) {
                var li = "";
                $.each(resp, function (i, v) {
                    li+="<li>"+v+"</li>";
                });
                console.log(li);
                $('#resp').html(li);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

*Members_view.php*: `<ul id="resp">` created to show response data.

```
<select id="group_id">
    <?php foreach($groups as $row){?>
        <option value="<?=$row['group'];?>">
            <?=$row['group'];?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<ul id="resp">Will be shown here!</ul>
```

Comment: It still doesn´t work. It seems like the controller doesn´t get the data. I tried something else with json and it still didn´t work. So I need to figure out why the data isn´t comming through

Comment: If you can see the `console.log` response, then the `controller` is getting data normally. If `console.log` is undefined, you just need to pay attention to the response format that is passed to `$.each(resp, function (i, v) {li+="<li>"+v+"</li>";});`. The only sign that the `controller` don't get data is the response absence. Use `$('#resp').html(resp);` to see what is comming from `controller` ;)